# Ipython Notebook, Twython, and Image(Pofile_image_tweet), No image?

Tags: python, image, ipython

wonderful community !
I'm using the Twython library , and I have a doubt.
I would like to display images or image twitter profile in IPython Notebook and I have not managed to do . I used *Image ( tweets [user ] [ profile_image_url ] )* but ipython notebook not pictured ! ... Any suggestions ?

I have the url of the image, but not HTML or Image () , let me display the picture, is an ipython notebook settings , what is the problem ?

Thanks and sorry , my English is not very good , I speak Spanish and French.

Code:

```
from twython import Twython
from IPython.display import display_pretty, display_html, display_jpeg, display_png, display_json, display_latex, display_svg
from IPython.display import Image

TWITTER_APP_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

t = Twython(TWITTER_APP_KEY, TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,       TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

search = t.search(q='#Nike', count=10)

tweets = search['statuses']
for tweet in tweets:
    print (tweet['user']['name'])
    i = Image(url=tweet['user']['profile_image_url'])
    i
```

Result's:

- VigLink Insider
- Cosmo Shop Γαελ
- .✮ adivigo sport
- MR.BOBBIE BAREND
- jessfitness22

Remember, Ipython Notebook !!

Image(url=tweet['user']['profile_image_url']) –  Tom Dalton --> D'ont works !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you are using, as well as the full text of any errors or tracebacks. We can't help you if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Ref the docs: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Display%20System.ipynb it seems to suggest you can just do `Image(url='http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif')`

Comment: You're doing the right thing, but we only automatically display something from the last line of a cell, and not if it's in a loop (because displaying a million things is bad). Call `IPython.display.display(i)` and you should see it.

Comment: Eureka !, worked, but of course only one profile.
If I want to see all pictures IPython notebook different twitter profiles , they can not be in a loop , then what would be the correct method to view them all ?